# Is the set of approximating sequences for irrationals dominating?

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic, real-analysis, posets, continued-fractions

Let $r\in [0,1]\setminus\mathbb{Q}$, let $\mathbb{N}$ denote the set of non-negative integers and let $\mathbb{N}_+=\mathbb{N}\setminus\{0\}$. For $n\in\mathbb{N}_+$ let  $$\alpha_r(n)=\min\{|r-\frac{m}{n}|: m\in\mathbb{N}\}$$ be the best approximation of $r$ that can be obtained using $n$ as the denominator.

We inductively define $\text{appr}_r:\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$, the *approximation sequence* of $r$:

- $\text{appr}_r(0) = 1$, and
- $\text{appr}_r(n+1) = \min\{m\in\mathbb{N}: m \geq \text{appr}_r(n) \text{ and } \alpha_r(m) < \alpha_r(\text{appr}_r(n))\}$ for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$.

Let $\mathbb{N}^\mathbb{N}$ denote the set of all functions $f:\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N}$. Given $f, g:\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N}$ we say $f\leq^* g$ iff there is $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $f(k) \leq g(k)$ for all $k\geq N$.

We say ${\cal D}\subseteq \mathbb{N}^\mathbb{N}$ is *dominating* if for all $f\in \mathbb{N}^\mathbb{N}$ there is $d\in {\cal D}$ such that $f\leq^* d$, and we say ${\cal B}\subseteq \mathbb{N}^\mathbb{N}$ is *unbounded* if for all $f\in\mathbb{N}^\mathbb{N}$ there is $b\in {\cal B}$ such that $b\not\leq^*f$. (A diagonalization argument shows that every unbounded (and therefore also every dominating) family must be uncountable, and there are interesting set-theoretical considerations in this context, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinal_characteristic_of_the_continuum).)

**Question.** Is $$\{\text{appr}_r: r\in[0,1]\setminus\mathbb{Q}\}\subseteq \mathbb{N}^\mathbb{N}$$ dominating? If not, is it unbounded?

Comment: The $\alpha$ in inductive the definition of $\text{appr}_r$ is in fact $\alpha_r$, right?

Comment: Oh - right, sorry for that mistake, will amend!

Comment: Yes, I think this family should be dominating. The idea is the following: for $f \in \mathbb{N_+}^\mathbb{N}$ define $r:= \sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \frac{1}{2^{f(n)}}$. Then $\text{appr}_r$ should dominate $f$.