# "Almost rational" irrational

Tags: real-analysis, approximation-theory, diophantine-approximation

This is a follow-up to an [older question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/393373/is-the-set-of-approximating-sequences-for-irrationals-dominating).

Let $r\in \mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q}$, let $\mathbb{N}$ denote the set of non-negative integers and let $\mathbb{N}_+=\mathbb{N}\setminus\{0\}$. For $n\in\mathbb{N}_+$ let  $$\alpha_r(n)=\min\{|r-\frac{m}{n}|: m\in\mathbb{N}\}$$ be the best approximation of $r$ that can be obtained using $n$ as the denominator.

We inductively define $\text{appr}_r:\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$, the *approximation sequence* of $r$:

- $\text{appr}_r(0) = 1$, and
- $\text{appr}_r(n+1) = \min\{m\in\mathbb{N}: m \geq \text{appr}_r(n) \text{ and } \alpha_r(m) < \alpha_r(\text{appr}_r(n))\}$ for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$.

For $A\subseteq {\mathbb N}$ we say that $A$ is **thin** if $\lim\sup_{n\to\infty}\frac{|A\,\cap \,\{1,\ldots,n+1\}|}{n+1} = 0.$ We say that $r\in\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q}$ is **almost rational** if the image of $\text{appr}_r$ is a thin subset of $\mathbb{N}$.

**Question.** Is there an almost rational $r\in\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q}$?

Comment: A better question is: Are there "not almost rational numbers"? The answer is all irrational numbers are "almost rational" in your sense. All terms in your approximation sequence are denominators of convergents and semiconvergents of $r$ (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continued_fraction ). That set is thin for any irrational number.